# fetch вместо XML

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли реализовать следующее при помощи fetch

1. Отправить запрос на получение изображения, по ссылке.
2. Запрос отправили, далее необходимо отобразить процесс загрузки. От сервера к пользователю, то есть отобразить каков % от веса файла, в данный момент получил пользователь
3. Выполнить код, повесить прослушиватель, когда пользователь загрузил файл и браузер готов его отобразить

Вот интересно, в данный момент реализовано это при помощи XMLHttpRequest. Собираюсь переделать на fetch если это возможно. Собственно вопрос, стоит ли это делать, в чем разница между двумя подходами, что лучше?

Comment: Возможно. . . .

Comment: Я так понимаю fetch лучше, но в чем?